# How to get the total of days and subtract affected weekends between two datetimepickers

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have two `Datetimepicker` and I need to get the total of days.

```
totalOfDays = Datetimepicker1 + Datetimepicker2 - affected weekends.
Datetimepicker1.Value.date = Wednesday, April 1 2020
Datetimepicker2.Value.date = Wednesday, April 22 2020
```

`totalOfDays` should be 15, not 21.

How to write this in C#?

Comment: What have you tried already? Anything on Google?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Dude thank you for this it really solved my problem, appreciate your help thank you.